# How we get in postgres daily inserted, updated and deleted records as a dump file?

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

We are creating dump file of multiple database as whole on every one hour but problem is storage and time of restoration. Please suggest me any solution

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to pipe in records from one server to another. Ideally, you use pglogical replication (available in core since version 10) and do it that way.

If you really need to continue the hourly pg_dump:
 - you can start using the **`-Fc`** flag for the *compressed* format, which will make your backups smaller
 - you can try [pgBackRest](https://pgbackrest.org/), which does full, incremental, and differential backups